Problem connecting springboot to mysql with docker-compose
I am developing a small application using springboot with maven and a mysql db.
I created a Dockerfile that's working but when I try to do docker-compose up the connection from app to db is refused.
here my docker-compose
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: jayaz98/angelodaleotest:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/angelodaleoptdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: docker-mysql
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: angelodaleoptdb
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      timeout: 5s

my application.properties
spring.application.name=project
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/angelodaleoptdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=100000
spring.datasource.hikari.initializationFailTimeout=0
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.servlet.context-path=/angelodaleopt

and this is the error i get from the app, with the db logs
2024-09-26 00:40:53 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:40:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
2024-09-26 00:40:53 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:40:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-09-26 00:40:53 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:40:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
2024-09-26 00:40:53 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:40:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2024-09-26 00:40:53 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:53.473629Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) initializing of server in progress as process 42
2024-09-26 00:40:53 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:53.481794Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-26 00:40:53 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:53.845476Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-09-26 00:40:54 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:54.943102Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2024-09-26 00:40:54 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:54.943145Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2024-09-26 00:40:54 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:54.994521Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:40:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:40:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.361816Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 91
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.373966Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.506201Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.719550Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.719583Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.720212Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.720267Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.722339Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.734210Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:40:58.734321Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-09-26 00:40:58 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:40:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
2024-09-26 00:40:59 db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2024-09-26 00:40:59 db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:41:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database angelodaleoptdb
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:41:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user admin
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:41:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user admin access to schema angelodaleoptdb
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | 
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:41:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2024-09-26 00:41:00 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:00.658231Z 13 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.27).
2024-09-26 00:41:02 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:02.352849Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-09-26 00:41:02 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:41:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
2024-09-26 00:41:02 db-1   | 
2024-09-26 00:41:02 db-1   | 2024-09-25 22:41:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
2024-09-26 00:41:02 db-1   | 
2024-09-26 00:41:02 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:02.878815Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 1
2024-09-26 00:41:02 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:02.885905Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.000695Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.177047Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.177090Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.177808Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.177859Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.179999Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.191853Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-09-26 00:41:03 db-1   | 2024-09-25T22:41:03.192079Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  | 
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)
2024-09-26 00:41:04 app-1  | 
2024-09-26 00:41:05 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:05.008  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.a.project.ProjectApplication           : Starting ProjectApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.16 on 4815623c35dd with PID 1 (/opt/opt/app.jar started by root in /opt)
2024-09-26 00:41:05 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:05.014  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.a.project.ProjectApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-09-26 00:41:05 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:05.977  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.038  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.587  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.600  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.601  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.671  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/angelodaleopt]           : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.671  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1579 ms
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.839  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.a.project.cors.SimpleCORSFilter        : SimpleCORSFilter init
2024-09-26 00:41:06 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:06.974  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-09-26 00:41:07 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:07.020  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2024-09-26 00:41:07 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:07.215  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2024-09-26 00:41:07 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:07.302  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-09-26 00:41:12 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:41:12.471  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  | 2024-09-25 22:42:52.482  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  | 
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  | java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 100002ms.
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2024-09-26 00:42:52 app-1  |    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
...

I tried everything I know but its not sufficient

You aren't opening anyports for the MySQL container, so nothing can access it.

@M.Deinum is wrong, the container can be accessed by other containers on the same network using the service name, just as you specified in the SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL.
However, in your application code you're still trying to connect to localhost

@DeanAyalon Am I wrong or when the docker-compose is present the application.properties goes in second place ?

You can add spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false which will delay the connection obtaining. You will need to specify spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect as that won't be detected now (spring.jpa.database-platform with the dialect will work as well).

The issue comes to the SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL env variable. You should add allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true with useSSL=false.
jdbc:mysql://db:3306/angelodaleoptdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true

allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true allows the JDBC driver to request the public key from the server automatically. By default, client libraries will not send the password unless a secure connection (using TLS or RSA public key encryption) can be established. To avoid a MITM attack, the RSA public key will not be sent in plain text.
It will also work without allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true and useSSL=false.
jdbc:mysql://db:3306/angelodaleoptdb?autoReconnect=true


ok the connection is estabilished, but now it says: Error executing DDL "create table acquisti (id integer not null auto_increment, data_acquisto datetime not null, email varchar(255) not null, id_scheda integer not null, token varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement, do you suggest creating another question ?

That is another question, your connection issue has been resolved. Don't use comments or an edit to the question to ask another question, open a new question instead and provide sufficient details.

You're trying to use localhost in your application properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/angelodaleoptdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
Use the service name
Edit: Wrong, the environment variable takes precedence apparently

I used to know that when the docker-compose is present the application.properties goes in second place

Sorry, I've no experience with Spring and do not know how it acts in such a case, however you should try to replace the url and see if it works, unfortunately there's not enough information in the logs to see what url it's trying to connect to

He is not using localhost, the SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL in the environment overrides the one in the application.properties. As environment properties take precedence (which is also explained in the Spring Boot documentation). So unless he has a persistence.xml which specifies a URL as well with localhost, this is wrong.

Then my answer is not the solution, thanks for the clarification.

Do you know a way where I can veirfy the url its tryng to connect ?
